# Get SharePoint online list metadata without Graph

Tags: c#, powershell, sharepoint-online

Is there a way to get the field names and types of a particular SharePoint list using Powershell (preferably) or C#?  This is what I've tried.  Either it hangs or says Get-PnPList : The query expression 'Param_0.Fields.ElementType' is not supported.
We're not allowed to use Graph.

```
#Set Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://MyCompany.sharepoint.com/teams-and-projects/dev"
$ListName = "TechDevWorkRequests"

#Connect to SharePoint Online site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin


Get-PnPList -Identity Lists/$ListName -Includes Fields.ElementType
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

This works apart from the if statement.

```
#Set Parameters
$SiteURL = https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/teams-and-projects/dev

$ListName = "TechDevWorkRequests"

#Connect to SharePoint Online site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL #-UseWebLogin

$columns = Get-PnPField -List $ListName 
foreach($column in $columns)
{  
if ($column.Group -eq "Custom Columns" -and $column.Hidden -eq "False")  
#if statement doesn’t filter output.  Not sure why.
{

        Write-Host "Column Title  :" $column.Title  
        Write-Host "Description   :" $column.Description  
        Write-Host "Group Name    :" $column.Group  
        Write-Host "Hidden?       :" $column.Hidden
        Write-Host "Internal Name :" $column.InternalName  
        Write-Host "Static Name   :" $column.StaticName  
        Write-Host "Scope         :" $column.Scope  
        Write-Host "Type          :" $column.TypeDisplayName  
        Write-Host "Schema XML    :" $column.SchemaXml  
        Write-Host "Is Required?  :" $column.Required  
        Write-Host "Is read only? :" $column.ReadOnlyField  
        Write-Host "Unique?       :" $column.EnforceUniqueValues  
        Write-Host "-------------------------------------------"  

 
    }
}
```